# Insert new line into excel EPPlus

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

Working with an excel document and have a small trouble with inserting new line into merge range address. Problem is, that it inserting two strings without new line, but when i'm double clicking on this merge address range, it automatically inserts new line.

```
using (var excel = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var workSheetAudit = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(AuditReportSheet);
    var description = workSheetAudit.Cells[ReportDescription]; //A2:G2

    description.Value = $"Company: Client Name {Environment.NewLine}Generated Date:  08-Jul-20AZ";

    //Styling
    using (description)
    {
        description.Merge = true;
        description.Style.Font.Size = 8;
        description.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
        description.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        description.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        description.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(153, 51, 102));
        description.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Left;
        description.Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Top;
        description.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
    }
     var stream = new MemoryStream(excel.GetAsByteArray());
     return stream;
```

}

Comment: add description.Style.WrapText = true; it is false by default

Comment: @ManishGoswami Thanks, that's solve my problem.